# SSH to clients in VPN - connection refused

Tags: networking, openvpn, openssh, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to set up an OpenVPN network and allow computers on that network to SSH to one another. The reason for this setup is that one of the computers has a DHCP connection, and is behind a router whose ports I don't have access to. All computers are running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server.

We have three machines:

- Machine A: OpenVPN Server
- Machine B: OpenVPN Client, SSH Server
- Machine C: OpenVPN Client, SSH Client trying to connect to Machine B.

I can connect to B when going through the regular (non-VPN) connection, but the connection gets refused when passed through the VPN. From B `/var/log/syslog`: `Connection from C refused by tcp_wrappers`. From C verbose SSH output: `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`.

Here's the info I have:

- OpenVPN uses UDP
- On B, SSH is listening on *:ssh, :::ssh, and ::1:6010
- VPN clients are visible to one another
- On B, port 22 is unblocked (nmap from C shows 22 as open)
- C uses the same certificate for both SSH connections
- B is connected to A via a direct ethernet connection (address 10.1.1.x). VPN addresses are in (10.8.0.x), and are fixed.
- B's software firewall is disabled (there is a hard firewall, but since we can SSH through it without the VPN I don't think it's the problem).

My question: How can I connect to B via SSH from C through the VPN? Based on the above info, is there something I'm overlooking which is preventing the connection from being established?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well the question,

> Connection from C refused by tcp_wrappers

points to the point why is you connection rejected. What is content of your files `/etc/hosts.deny` and `/etc/hosts.allow`?

Comment: `/etc/hosts.deny` is all comments, and `/etc/hosts.allow` has `sendmail: all`

Comment: just to make sure. Is it really on machine B, where this message appeared?

Comment: Yes, the message appeared on machine B (SSH Server), and refused the connection coming from C's VPN address.

Comment: I meant the files, if they are on machine B. Does something change if you comment out everything/leave it empty?

Comment: Yes, they're on B. Commenting everything out has no effect.